# Can I populate a collection of Eloquent models from a static array?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and its Eloquent model with mysql.

But I would like to populate a collection of models fetching a static array and then querying it as normal.
So let's say I have my Photo model and I would query it as usual:

```
App\Photo::where('published', 1)->get();
```

But the Photo model should fetch not a DB table but an array like this:

```
$photos = [ 
    [ "id" => 1, "published" => 1 ],
    [ "id" => 2, "published" => 1 ],
    [ "id" => 2, "published" => 0 ],
]
```

My problem is to link this array to that model before querying it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: i think this doc can solve your problem please read this doc, http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections, once you fetch data with eloquent you can filter the record over and over with querying back to database.

Comment: @KA_lin I can't because I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: @umefarooq thanks but I can't find any clue about my purpose: the User model of the example provided is still fetching from a real DB table and then using a Collection/Array class for the result.

Comment: I was thinkin of a pseudocode or how you wish for this to work on a macro scale

Comment: @KA_lin yeah i know what you mean: i've just updated my question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know why you want this but if I were you I would put **every** query method in a service class:

```
namespace App\Services;
class PhotoService implements PhotoServiceInterface
{
    public function getAllPhotos() {
        return App\Photo::$photos;
    }

    //your static array defined in the class as an associative array, you should use **try** **catch** for this or define a default if the key does not exist
    public static function getPhotoById($id) {
        return App\Photo::$photos[$id];
    }

    //other functions
    public function getAllAlbums() {
        return App\Albums::all();
    }
}
```

This way if you want to put them in a table or other changes occur in your app you just have to change this class.

**Problem:**
If you have a model that has a relation to this model you would have to use the service to get it (`getPhotoById($user->getPhotoId())`) rather than for ex `$user->getPhoto()`.
Or you can:

```
class User
{
    ....
    public function getPhoto() {
        return App\Services\PhotoService::getPhotoById($this->photo_id);
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the lists functionality will return an array of the columns that you specify in the query.

```
 App\Photo::where('published', 1)->lists('id','published');
```

Hence you can query the model what ever way you want the have it return an array of the fields placed inside lists functionality